# Passing Nil Value Through Link_to to controller value missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Updated

Per the answer below here is my new link_to

```
<%= link_to "Post a Question", new_classifieds_question_path(@classified) %>
```

and my controller

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def new
    @classified = Classified.find(params[:classified_id])
    @question = Question.new 
  end 

  def create
    @classified = Classified.find(params[:classified_id])
    @question = Question.new(params[:question])
    @classified.questions << @question
    if @question.save 
      flash[:notice] = "Question has been posted"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "It did not go through"
    end
  end
end
```

new routes

```
  resource :classifieds do 
    resources :questions
  end
```

classified model

```
class Classified < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
end
```

and question model

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :question_body, :classifieds_id

  belongs_to :classified
end
```

and my new error

```
Couldn't find Classified without an ID
```

---

I have a questions controller with two new/create methods

```
  def new
    @question = Question.new 
  end 

  def create
    @question = Question.new(params[:question])
    @question.classifieds_id = @classified.id
#@question.classifieds_id = params[:id]
    if @question.save 
      flash[:notice] = "Question has been posted"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "It did not go through"
    end
  end
```

A question belongs_to a classified ad. The questions table in the schema has a classifieds_id column.

Here is my question model

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :question_body, :classifieds_id

  belongs_to :classified
end
```

in my routes.rb

```
resources :questions
```

Here is one variation of my link_to (in my show.html.erb)

This is my show method in another controller

```
  def show
    @classified=Classifieds.find(params[:id])
  end


  <td>
    <%= link_to "Post a Question", new_question_path(@classified) %>
  </td>
```

I am trying to pass the id of the classified instance to be processed by the questions controller.

I have tried many version of a link_to, like this

```
  <td>
    <%= link_to "Post a Question", new_question_path(:id => @classified.id) %>
  </td>
```

and like this

```
  <td><%= link_to "Post a Question", {:controller => "questions", :action => "new", :classified_id => @classified.id }, :class => "btn btn-default btn-lg" %></td>
  <tr>
```

The hacks just isn't working and searching questions on stackoverflow isn't working either.

I have tried doing this in show.html.erb

```
  <p>
    <%= @classified.id %>
  </p>
```

and the value gets outputted. I got better errors installed and a `nil value` gets passed in.

using `gem 'rails', '3.2.13'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have nested resources in your routes...

```
resources :classifieds do
  resources :questions
end
```

That will give you the method

```
<%= link_to "Post a question", new_classifieds_question_path(@classified) %>
```

Your new method will receive the classified_id

```
def new
  @classified = Classified.find(params[:classified_id])
  @question = Question.new
end

def create
  @classified = Classified.find(params[:classified_id])
  @question = Question.new(params[:question]
  @classified.questions << @question
   ...
end
```

EDIT
Sorry, forgot the `_path` in the path call, now fixed.

Comment: I think you should close your statements in the method with ')', and it should be `new_classifieds_question_path`. I am getting this error `uninitialized constant QuestionsController::Classified`.

Comment: Well spotted!  I notice in your solution you refer to the model `Classifieds`... by rails convention the model should be called `Classified` and the table `classifieds`, so to make your life easier you should fix that.

Comment: I think it should be `<%= link_to "Post a question", new_classifieds_question(:classified_id => @classified.id) %>` because in your statement its looking for a `params[:classified_id]`. I changed the model to singular form :). Only that model is not singular..... but now when I click on the link_to I am getting `undefined method questions_path ` now that the route change should the `new.html.erb` still be under `views/questions/new.html.erb?`

Comment: No, my fault, it should have been `new_classifieds_question_path` ... I forgot the `_path` bit.  You can just pass @classified and the rails path helper is smart enough to extract out the id and assign it to the right variable name.

Comment: I put in new updates. You didn't leave out the `_path` part. The rails path helper is not extracting the id. I am getting undefined id.

Comment: Is your model `Classifieds` or `Classified` ?  It should be the singular.

Comment: it use to be `Classifieds` and `classifieds.rb` I changed it to `Classified` and `classified.rb` should I change it to `Clasified`? and the table name is `classifieds` right now.

Comment: yes, `class Classified < ActiveRecord::Base` copied from classified.rb file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57448/discussion-between-steveturczyn-and-jngai1297).

Comment: You got me through passing the id through the link_to, and that is the answer to this question.